# Grayscale images in Joomla supporting IE 10

Tags: css, svg, joomla, explorer, grayscale

I have been reading for grayscale image support for a while now. I have found the solution with using CSS code in my template.css:

```
    .partner {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
  filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+ & Safari 6+ */
}

.partner:hover {
  filter: none;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

For image itself I am using:

```
<img class="partner" src="/joom/images/partners/image.png" alt="image logo" height="30" width="105">
```

However this doesn't work with IE9 and next versions of IE10, 11... I know that I should use SVG to get it working on IE10. So I need to use both CSS and JS. What files and what codes do I need to use to get SVG grayscale support for images?
Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IE10/11 you must display the image via an SVG `<image>` element and not an html `<img>` element. Only SVG elements can be subject to filters in IE. i.e.

```
<svg height="30" width="105">
    <image class="partner" xlink:href="/joom/images/partners/image.png"  height="30" width="105">
        <desc>image logo</desc>
    </image>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but I need the code of SVG or JQuery file and some guide of how to connect it with my Joomla template files

Comment: I have solved this problem using JCE editor with onmouseover